# what is the loss function in char recognition using Tensorflow?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, convolution, ocr

I have code in Tensorflow using convolution neural network to recognize the characters in street view Text (SVT) data.

Since the label type is string, what should I use instead of `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` in the loss function?

I cannot use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` because the labels her must be an int dtype??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loss function is correct, you just need to convert categorical variables into numerical representations using one-hot vector encoding. Please take a look at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-categorical-features).